# Using PrettyTable in python with clickable html links as a column

Tags: python, hyperlink, prettytable

I am creating a table in python using pretty-table and trying to have one column which are the urls have clickable links:

Eg:

```
filepath = "pretty_table.html"

from prettytable import PrettyTable
x = PrettyTable()
x.format = True

x = PrettyTable(["City name", "Area", "Url"])

x.add_row(["Adelaide",1295, "<a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelaide'>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelaide</a>" ])
x.add_row(["Brisbane",5905, "<a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brisbane'>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brisbane</a>"])

result = []
result.append(x.get_html_string())

with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    for line in result:
        f.write("{}\n".format(line))
```

However, with the above, the table doesn't generate clickable links for the wiki pages. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

```py
    import html
    url = 'https://www.baidu.com' # link to point to
    pt.add_row(['2018-10-10','<a href=\"' + url + '\">' + url + '</a>'])
    text = pt.get_html_string(format=True)
    text = html.unescape(text)   # crucial step
```

More information can be found [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/7720226605/)