# Add HTML formatted Caption for PrettyTable Title

Tags: python, html, prettytable

I am trying to render an HTML table using PrettyTable python package. I need to have HTML formatted caption for the table but for some reason PrettyTable is replacing `<` with `&lt;`, `"` with `&quot;` and `>` with `&gt;`

Below is my code snippet:

```
>>> from prettytable import PrettyTable
>>> table = PrettyTable()
>>> table.field_names = ["Name", "Email", "Phone"]
>>> table.add_row(["John Smith", "john.smith@email.com", "XXX-XXX-XXXX"])
>>> table
+------------+----------------------+--------------+
|    Name    |        Email         |    Phone     |
+------------+----------------------+--------------+
| John Smith | john.smith@email.com | XXX-XXX-XXXX |
+------------+----------------------+--------------+
>>> print(table.get_html_string(title='<a href="www.example.com">Table</a>'))
<table>
    <caption>&lt;a href=&quot;www.example.com&quot;&gt;Table&lt;/a&gt;</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John Smith</td>
            <td>john.smith@email.com</td>
            <td>XXX-XXX-XXXX</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
>>>
```

How can I make PrettyTable to render the HTML formatted title properly?

Comment: It [always escapes](https://github.com/jazzband/prettytable/blob/main/src/prettytable/prettytable.py#L2165), so you need to manually inject the HTML. See [this issue](https://github.com/jazzband/prettytable/issues/40).

Comment: @ivvija, got it! But https://stackoverflow.com/a/65382954/8393140 helped me!

Answer (score 0):

This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65382954/8393140) helped me to find the solution!

Below is my solution:

```
>>> import html
>>> from prettytable import PrettyTable
>>> table = PrettyTable()
>>> table.field_names = ["Name", "Email", "Phone"]
>>> table.add_row(["John Smith", "john.smith@email.com", "XXX-XXX-XXXX"])
>>> table
+------------+----------------------+--------------+
|    Name    |        Email         |    Phone     |
+------------+----------------------+--------------+
| John Smith | john.smith@email.com | XXX-XXX-XXXX |
+------------+----------------------+--------------+
>>> unescaped = html.unescape(table.get_html_string(title='<a href="www.example.com">Table</a>'))
>>> print(unescaped)
<table>
    <caption><a href="www.example.com">Table</a></caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John Smith</td>
            <td>john.smith@email.com</td>
            <td>XXX-XXX-XXXX</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
>>>
```